# Syntax for properly returning and storing references in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, reference

In the following code:

```
class Foo {

    Object Bar;

    Object& getBar1()
    {
        return Bar;
    }

    Object& getBar2()
    {
        return &Bar;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    Foo instance();

    Object A = instance.getBar1();
    Object& B = instance.getBar1();

    Object X = instance.getBar2();
    Object& Y = instance.getBar2();

}
```

What are the differences between `getBar1()` and `getBar2()`, if any?
Also, which is the correct way of getting the reference to `Bar` so that I could manipulate the contents of `Bar`?

Comment: `Foo instance();` declares a *function* named `instance`, which take no arguments and returns a `Foo` object by value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. For clarification, in the line `Object A = instance.getBar1();` , would `A` behave identically if the function definition changed from `Object& getBar1()` to `Object getBar1()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just because `&` appear in both cases does not mean that it does the same thing.

When you write `SomeType &` you are declaring "a reference to an object of type `SomeType`. When you write `& someObject` you are asking the a pointer that points to `someObject`.

Both `getBar1` and `getBar2` signatures say that they don't receive any argument and that they return a reference to an object of the type `Object`. That means that in their implementation you must return an object of type `Object`. But in the implementation of `getBar2` you are returning a pointer to an object of type `Object` instead of an object. Thus, it won't even compile.

---

Now let's discuss about "storing references".

When you write `Object A = instance.getBar1();` the `getBar1` function does return a reference, however, it is copied to variable `A` (the copy constructor of `Object` will be used to initialize `A`).

Only when you write `Object& B = instance.getBar1();` is that you "store a reference". In that case, `B` will be a reference to the object returned by `getBar1`, which must still exist. In that case no constructor will be called, and we can see `B` as just an alias for whatever object was returned by `getBar1`.

Answer (score 0):

`getBar2()` will not compile, as `return &Bar;` returns an `Object*` pointer, not an `Object&` reference.

But, assuming you return a proper reference, then

`Object A = instance.getBar1();`

and

`Object X = instance.getBar2();`

are making a *copy* of the returned `Object`, so any changes you make to the `Object` will be on the copy, not on the original.

Using

`Object& B = instance.getBar1();`

and

`Object& Y = instance.getBar2();`

any changes made to the returned `Object` will be made on the original.  Likewise if you fix `getBar2()` to return an `Object*` pointer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
    int value;

public:
    Object() : value(0) {}

    void display() const
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }

    void setValue(int val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
};

class Foo
{
    Object Bar;

public:
    Object& getBar1()
    {
        return Bar;
    }

    Object* getBar2()
    {
        return &Bar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo instance;

    Object  A = instance.getBar1();
    Object& B = instance.getBar1();
    Object* C = &(instance.getBar1());

    A.setValue(1);
    B.setValue(2);
    C->setValue(3);

    A.display();
    B.display();
    C->display();

    Object  X = *(instance.getBar2());
    Object& Y = *(instance.getBar2());
    Object* Z = instance.getBar2();

    X.setValue(4);
    Y.setValue(5);
    Z->setValue(6);

    X.display();
    Y.display();
    Z->display();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
3
4
6
6
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/noGt5g)